# Intellisense for DataGridView column names when using a List<T> as the Datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has 4 columns that need to be formatted.  The dataSource for this DataGridView is a generic list of objects from a class with 4 properties.

At design time, how can I use **intelisense** to specify the column?

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
List<MyDataRow> myDataList = new List<MyDataRow>();

   // List is populated in this section of code...

dgv.DataSource = myDataList;
dgv.Columns["ALongDescriptiveNameThatCouldEasilyBeMistyped"].Width = 80;    .

   // dgv is added to a form and displayed in this section of code

public class MyDataRow
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double ALongDescriptiveNameThatCouldEasilyBeMistyped { get; set; }
    public int YearsOfService { get; set; }
    public int MonthsOfService { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following class which contains a method using an expression tree as an argument to determine a member name based on a lambda expression:

```
public class MemberHelper<T> where T : class
{
    public string GetName<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(memberExpression != null)
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Member expression expected");
    }
}
```

You can use the method like so:

```
MemberHelper<MyDataRow> memberHelper = new MemberHelper<MyDataRow>();
dgv.Columns[memberHelper.GetName(d => d.FirstName)].Width = 80;
```

Comment: I really like this approach.  I have a number of classes with MANY columns that are frequently changed during development.  StackOverflow members are amazing.

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer - One thing to note is that this approach will be measurably slower than using strings or integers to access the columns collection. But I guess having strongly typed code outweighs the small performance penalty at runtime and this is not an uncommon approach, most notably used in ASP.NET MVC (Html Helpers). Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to declare enumeration which contains your column names with assigned integer values from 0 to N , and use that enum for Index based access to the columns of DataGrid.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
enum ColumnNames
{
    ColumnName1 = 0, 
    ColumnName2 = 1,
    ColumnName3 = 2,
     .....
      .....
}
```

Comment: Thansk @Tigran This approach could be helpful. However, if the property name is refactored, the enumeration doesn't change.  If another property is added in the middle of the class the enum would also need to be modified. I guess I could keep the enum right next to the class... but isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @DawwinIcesurfer: Don't really think you can do what you want, in this case. Cause, if you want to support refactoring of the property, change of the class, you AT LEAST, will need some code generator (like InitializeComponenets or Resources of WinForms), but even if you will be able to do something like this, at some point you should signal to that functionality to regenerate the stuff, so it will never be something "automatic". May be something like this can be achieved by writing down a plugin, but honestly, don't know if this worth all that work. May be someone will offer more clever solut

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense will not help, because Columns is just int/string indexer. You can use attributes on properties and some reflection and then Linq query constructing string array containing names of properties decorated with specific attribute, but maybe it's not worth it in your case.